# Keeping OID field when exporting to CSV?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, csv

I imported a csv file and converted it to gdb format, and now I want to export it back to csv.

The file will be the exact same as before I imported it, except I want to keep the ArcMap generated OID.

However, when I export the file to csv, the OID field is lost, and contains null values only.

I understand why this is the case, because the OID is a temporary variable I guess.

Is there anything I can do to keep it though? Perhaps duplicate the field, but I am not sure how to do that in ArcMap.

Comment: Please be more specific about your problem. You imported a csv file and converted to gdb-format? Can you explain this further? And do you want to export the complete gdb to csv or just a feature in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to keep the OID field. That should be simple, open attribute table, click on Add Field, name this new field for example OID_1, choose type (short integer or long integer for many features), and then use **Field calculator**.

[image]

The equation will be *OID_1 = [OID]*. After you click OK, it will copy OID values into OID_1. When the export is done, the field should be accessible.

Comment: Ah perfect, thank you! The only thing I had to do differently was to choose the long integer option, because I have 100,000 OID's, as the short integer ID created errors.